# Получение всех фоновых процессов текущего приложения C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Как получить все фоновые процессы текущего приложения на C# Windows Forms?

Comment: UPD: Решено. Код:  Process[] ir = Process.GetProcessesByName(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Application.ExecutablePath));

Comment: Сергей, ответы — в ответы.